# Using strtotime to output all weeks not working Mon-Sun but is for Sun-Sat PHP

Tags: php, strtotime

I am attempting to output every week currently in this current year. I'm using the code shown below however it doesn't work when using Monday-Sunday.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < date("W"); $i++) 
{
echo '<option value="' . date("W", strtotime("this monday - $i week")) . '">' . date("M j Y", strtotime("this sunday - $i week")) . " - " . date("M j Y", strtotime("this saturday - $i week")) .'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Can you please define what do you mean by `it doesn't work when using Monday-Sunday` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologises all, I have found the solution very quickly after posting this. I realised that I needed to add rather than subtract this. Which gives me the output as:

"Aug 14 2017 - Aug 20 2017"

```
'<option value="' . date("W", strtotime("this monday - $i week")) . '">' . date("M j Y", strtotime("this monday - $i week")) . " - " . date("M j Y", strtotime("next sunday + $i week")) .'</option>'
```